# esp32 bluetooth disconnected after a few seconds

Tags: bluetooth, esp32

I wrote a simple program in c++ (using the Arduino ide) that opens a Serial Bluetooth connection.

```
#include "BluetoothSerial.h"

#if !defined(CONFIG_BT_ENABLED) || !defined(CONFIG_BLUEDROID_ENABLED)
#error Bluetooth is not enabled! Please run `make menuconfig` to and enable it
#endif

BluetoothSerial SerialBT;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  SerialBT.begin("ESP32test"); //Bluetooth device name
  Serial.println("The device started, now you can pair it with bluetooth!");
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()) {
    SerialBT.write(Serial.read());
  }
  if (SerialBT.available()) {
    Serial.write(SerialBT.read());
  }

}
```

the program runs, but when I am trying to connect to ESP32 with my phone it connects successfully but disconnects after a few seconds.

And when I am trying to connect to it via Bluetooth Terminal Application (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.kai_morich.serial_bluetooth_terminal&hl=en) the connection won't even start.

I tested the program with multiple ESP32 devices from different types (NODEMCU, WROOM) but all of them had the same problem.

Comment: Hi, were you able to resolve the issue? I have the exact same thing happening to me.

Comment: The problem was that the board wasn’t working properly, I bought a new one and it worked

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have a new device now too and it works.